# How use integer_sort from boost library?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, boost

I use boost::sort() from boost/range/algorithm.hpp but is really... slow and I'm just working with unsigned integer type, so I thought "Maybe using integer_sort() from boost/sort/spreadsort/integer_sort.hpp I can improve the speed"
The Question is that std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()) run in ~54 seconds and boost:sort(v) in ~54 seconds (Same time)

But I Write something like radix sort, and takes ~28 seconds, but I think that integer_sort can be more optimized that my code, but I don't know how use integer_sort.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/sort/spreadsort/integer_sort.hpp> // I WANT USE THIS
#include "myLib.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  vector <unsigned> v(20);

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    v[i] = rand() % 1000;

  imprime(v); // THIS PRINTS THE VECTOR
  boost::sort(v); // THIS SORT THE VECTOR
  imprime(v);
  integer_sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // THIS DOES'T WORK

  return 0;
}
```

If I try with integer_sort(v.begin(), v.end()); I get

```
sort.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sort.cpp:23:34: error: ‘integer_sort’ was not declared in this scope
   integer_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
                                  ^
sort.cpp:23:34: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from sort.cpp:5:0:
/usr/include/boost/sort/spreadsort/integer_sort.hpp:173:15: note:   ‘boost::sort::spreadsort::integer_sort’
   inline void integer_sort(RandomAccessIter first, RandomAccessIter last,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/sort/spreadsort/integer_sort.hpp:26:0,
                 from sort.cpp:5:
/usr/include/boost/sort/spreadsort/detail/integer_sort.hpp:482:5: note:   ‘boost::sort::spreadsort::detail::integer_sort’
     integer_sort(RandomAccessIter first, RandomAccessIter last, Div_type,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know that this has something to do with the (v.begin(), v.end()) `RandomAccessIter first` <- I get something similar when I try `std::sort(v)` <- this is not correct. But I don't understand the error message.
Don't say `candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided` like in std::sort.

**So How use integer_sort()?**

[Boost Doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/sort/doc/html/index.html) Says:

Each of integer_sort, float_sort, and string_sort have 3 main versions: The base version, which takes a first iterator and a last iterator, just like std::sort:

```
integer_sort(array.begin(), array.end());
float_sort(array.begin(), array.end());
string_sort(array.begin(), array.end());
```

Comment: Try to guess what `boost::sort::spreadsort::integer_sort` line in suggested alternatives means. And why did you wrote `boost::sort` before.

Comment: [Related boost bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11202) (not quite the same issue, but something that you might run into in this kind of test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a namespace qualification in your call to `integer_sort`.

`integer_sort` is in the `boost::sort::spreadsort` namespace (see [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/sort/doc/html/boost/sort/spreadsort/integer_sort_idp16395296.html)). So your call should look like:

```
boost::sort::spreadsort::integer_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Also note that you will have problems if you try to use `boost::sort` and the `Boost.Sort` library in the same program, as the `boost::sort` function template conflicts with the `Boost.Sort` namespace (see [the bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11202)).

`boost::sort` is just a wrapper for `std::sort`, so it is expected that the two would have identical performance.

`boost::sort::spreadsort::integer_sort` will use `std::sort` if the data size is too small (below `boost::sort::spreadsort::detail::min_sort_size`), so for small data sizes it would be expected that they too have nearly identical performance (up to the extra cost of `integer_sort` checking whether to use `std::sort` or not).